# Excel 2016 Conundrum: "Activate method of range class failed" error when trying to set focus to a cell in another workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have a form containing a treeview control listing errors found in another excel workbook. When an error is clicked in the treeview, I want to move the cursor to the appropriate cell in the other workbook, so that the user can correct the value of that cell. I have the following code:

```
Set wsNavigate = Worksheets(TargetWorksheet)

' Activate workbook
TargetWorkbook.Activate

' Activate worksheet
wsNavigate.Activate

' Activate and select cell
wsNavigate.Cells(cDestination.row, cDestination.column).Activate
wsNavigate.Cells(cDestination.row, cDestination.column).Select
```

This code works fine, if all Excel windows are maximized and on the same screen. However, if I move the form window to my other screen or simply restore down my Excel windows, then it only works the first time a link is clicked, after that I get an "Activate method of range class failed" error. The weird thing is, if I then go into debug mode, it works just fine.

This problem started occurring, when we started using Excel 2016 with the Single Document Interface. In older versions, the code worked fine.

I've searched and tried many different things, however, so far I have not been able to come up with a solution yet. It would be great, if someone could help.

Comment: what happnes if you modify `Set wsNavigate = Worksheets(TargetWorksheet)` to `Set wsNavigate = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(TargetWorksheet)` ?

Comment: Actually, I cut a little too much code off before. This is how I have it:

Set wsNavigate = TargetWorkbook.Worksheets(TargetWorksheet)

I think, that the problem is, that the focus seems to change back to the form (which is not in the target workbook), with each new line of code that is executed. However, when I'm in debug mode it doesn't.

Comment: You don't need to invoke the Range.Activate method. This method allows you to make a cell the active one __within the selection__. That's not your goal; you just need the Select call.

Comment: Thanks @Excelosaurus for the clarification. I had already tried that, however, then it gives me a "Select method of range class failed" error :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much research, the only solution to the problem that I could find, was to move the cursor to another sheet briefly before moving it to the desired cell. It's not pretty, but at least it works. Here is the code (new parts in bold):

```
Set wsNavigate = Worksheets(TargetWorksheet)
**Set wsTemp = Worksheets(SomeOtherWorksheet)**

' First activate other sheet
**wsTemp .Activate**

' Activate destination worksheet
wsNavigate.Activate

' Activate and select cell
wsNavigate.Cells(cDestination.row, cDestination.column).Activate
wsNavigate.Cells(cDestination.row, cDestination.column).Select
```